# Subset sum where the size of the subset is `k` is NPC?

Tags: reduction, np, np-complete, subset-sum, computability

I have a variation of [Subset-Sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) where the size of the subset is `k` and all the integers are positive (not zero).

As can be seen online, this question can be fairly solved using dynamic programming in pseudo-polynomial time.

I need to decide wether this problem is `NPC`, or in `P` (while assuming `P!=NP`).

I've tried to reduce from subset-sum problem, but had a problem with the constraint that all integers must be greater than zero. Since otherwise I would have just padded the input with `k` zero integers.

Formal definition of the problem:

`L={<S1,S2,...,Sn,T,k>|There exists a subset I of S1,...,Sn of size m which sums up to T}`

Comment: Might get better help on [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : ​ Would get closed on cstheory. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in NPC.

If you could find polynomial time solutions to your problem then you could have polynomial time solutions to Subset Sum problem with upper bound
Time of Subset Sum = k * (Your Problem's Time)

Comment: Your initial sentence is correct, but your argument only shows hardness under [disjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) reductions, not membership in NPC. ​ ​

Answer (score 2):

That problem is NPC. ​ In fact, when k is in n<sup>1-[Ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition)(1)</sup>, even the combination of

the numbers all being in n<sup>O(k)</sup>

with
the [promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem) that there is [at most one solution](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~paturi/myPapers/pubs/CalabroImpagliazzoKabanetsPaturi_2008_jcss.pdf)

is not suspected to put it in ​ [coN](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#conp)T[IME](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#ntime)(n^([o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(k))) / [2<sup>o(k*n*log(n))</sup>](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppoly) ​ infinitely-often,

since [this paper's Proof of Theorem 5.1](http://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/cnf-sat-feasible.pdf#page=12) gives a reduction

that works for such k and preserves the number of solutions.